# Looking for a book about a guy who travels through portal in the Vietnamese jungle

Tags: story-identification

I am trying to figure out what the name of a book is, which I read 15 years ago as a kid.

It is about a guy who travelled through some sort of portal (I do not know because this happened in a earlier book from this series, I believe) in the Vietnam jungle and got stuck in a new world. On this world he fights in an army for princes, dukes etc. The cover was dark red and paperback. Although I can vaguely remember him sitting on some kind of animal on the cover, I am not 100% certain. Could someone please help me find this book?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/225675/m-113-armored-vehicle-from-vietnam-to-sword-and-sorcery-land-fights-dragon (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Comment: I think that's the premise of the [Bifrost Guardians](https://www.goodreads.com/series/42462-bifrost-guardians) series by Mickey Zucker Reichert.  Haven't read them myself, though.

Answer (score 10):

This might be *The Starfollowers of Coramonde*, by Brian Daley.  It's the sequel to *Doomfarers of Coramonde*, in which the hero Gil MacDonald and the rest of his tank crew are transported from Vietnam to a fantasy world.

In the sequel he travels back by himself, after not being able to adapt to civilian life.  The cover of Doomfarers shows a warrior on horseback.

[image: Cover of The Doomfarers of Coramonde]